# How to create channel with socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, publish-subscribe, channel

I've started Python a few times ago and now, I'm currently creating a socket server. I already have the server functioning with multiple threads with multiple clients (Hurray !) But I'm looking for functionality I can't call (i don't even know if it exists) I would like to create a kind of channel where client can send different type of message.

An example I create a channel INFO and if the server received this type of socket it just does a print

I create another channel DEBUG where I can send custom command which the server will execute

etc

In a non-programming language it will do this:

```
def socketDebug(command):
     run command

def socketInfo(input):
     print input

if socket == socketDebug:
     socketDebug(socket.rcv)
else:
   if socket == socketInfo:
     socketInfo(socket.rcv)
```

I hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quite simple implementation of a Channel class. It creates a socket, to accept
connections from clients and to send messages. It is also a client itself,
receiving messages from other Channel instances (in separate processes for example).

The communication is done in two threads, which is pretty bad (I would use async io). when
a message is received, it calls the registered function *in the receiving thread* which
can cause some threading issues.

Each Channel instance creates its own sockets, but it would be much more scalable to
have channel "topics" multiplexed by a single instance.

Some existing libraries provide a "channel" functionality, like [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org).

The code here is for educational purposes, if it can help...

```
import socket
import threading

class ChannelThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    self.clients = []
    self.chan_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.chan_sock.bind(('',0))  
    _, self.port = self.chan_sock.getsockname()
    self.chan_sock.listen(5)
    self.daemon=True
    self.start()

  def run(self):
    while True:
      new_client = self.chan_sock.accept()
      if not new_client:
        break
      self.clients.append(new_client)

  def sendall(self, msg):
    for client in self.clients:
      client[0].sendall(msg)

class Channel(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    self.daemon = True
    self.channel_thread = ChannelThread()

  def public_address(self):
    return "tcp://%s:%d" % (socket.gethostname(), self.channel_thread.port)

  def register(self, channel_address, update_callback):
    host, s_port = channel_address.split("//")[-1].split(":")
    port = int(s_port)
    self.peer_chan_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
    self.peer_chan_sock.connect((host, port))
    self._callback = update_callback
    self.start()

  def deal_with_message(self, msg):
    self._callback(msg)

  def run(self):
    data = ""
    while True:
      new_data = self.peer_chan_sock.recv(1024)
      if not new_data:
        # connection reset by peer
        break
      data += new_data
      msgs = data.split("\n\n")
      if msgs[-1]:
        data = msgs.pop()
      for msg in msgs:
        self.deal_with_message(msg)

  def send_value(self, channel_value):
    self.channel_thread.sendall("%s\n\n" % channel_value)
```

## Usage:

In process A:

```
c = Channel()
c.public_address()
```

In process B:

```
def msg_received(msg):
  print "received:", msg

c = Channel()
c.register("public_address_string_returned_in_process_A", msg_received)
```

In process A:

```
c.send_value("HELLO")
```

In process B:

```
received: HELLO
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will go for this. And i'm also exploring the Redis Pub/Sub system.

Comment: This is just an example, for educational purpose. I am glad if it helps. The Redis pub/sub system is great (Redis is great!).